# AngularJS: ui-router-tabs selecting a default tab

Tags: angularjs

I am currently using the ui-router-tabs (https://github.com/rpocklin/ui-router-tabs) module in my application.

I have got most of it working as I need but I want to select a default tab.

Here is an example of how my states are currently configured (pretty much the way the example is from the site above!):

```
.state('state', {
  url: "/foo/:id/bar",
  controller: 'SomeController',
  templateUrl: 'pageA.html'
}).state('state.substateA', {
  url: "/somepath",
  templateUrl: 'partials/pageB.html',
  controller: 'SomeOtherController'
}).state('state.substateB', {
  url: "/someotherpath",
  templateUrl: 'partials/pageC.html',
  controller: 'AnotherController'
});
```

So at present if the url is "/foo/:id/bar" I want to select my first tab by default, is this something I ought to be doing at the controller level, so sniff the current matched state and if equal to "/foo/:id/bar" then trigger another state change manually?

**EDIT**

OK, so as I was writing the question I came up with a way, but not sure of it's really the angular way of doing it.

So in my controller code I check the current state and set a default sub state accordingly to end up selecting one of my tabs:

```
if ($state.current.name === 'state') {
  $state.go('state.substateA');
}
```

Does this seem like a sensible approach?

Comment: It's fine approach go ahead:)

Comment: hey, won't `$state.go('state.substateA');` in SomeController help? I mean after all the logic in `SomeController`, just do a `$state.go('state.substateA');` irrespective of the state. Because `Somecontroller` would get invoked when the state is 'state' right? If you are using `SomeController` for other states also, then your solution looks decent.

Comment: No I don't want to call $state.go('state.substateA') immediately in SomeController as that will mean if the url is "/foo/:id/bar/someotherpath" then 'state.substateB' wont get resolved since the $state.go(..) call will get in the way and break sticky selections of tabs by the user.